Flutter bloc emitted data not coming to the UI
I am making a flutter app and I want to show adds in the app. This is my first time working with admob. I created a test ad and it worked. I try to implement bloc because this app will eventually get big. But when I try to do that, it is not working.
Here is my home screen ui. Commented code here is the working one without bloc.
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

import 'bloc/ad_bloc.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final AdSize adSize = AdSize.banner;
  BannerAd? _bannerAd;

  final String adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid
      // Use this ad unit on Android...
      ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
      // ... or this one on iOS.
      : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // _loadAd();
    context
        .read<AdBloc>()
        .add(AdInit(adSize: AdSize.banner, adUnitId: adUnitId));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Loads a banner ad.
  // void _loadAd() {
  //   final bannerAd = BannerAd(
  //     size: adSize,
  //     adUnitId: adUnitId,
  //     request: const AdRequest(),
  //     listener: BannerAdListener(
  //       // Called when an ad is successfully received.
  //       onAdLoaded: (ad) {
  //         if (!mounted) {
  //           ad.dispose();
  //           return;
  //         }
  //         setState(() {
  //           _bannerAd = ad as BannerAd;
  //         });
  //       },
  //       // Called when an ad request failed.
  //       onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
  //         debugPrint('BannerAd failed to load: $error');
  //         ad.dispose();
  //       },
  //     ),
  //   );

  //   // Start loading.
  //   bannerAd.load();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF24405),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Topup Card Scanner'),
        ),
        body: BlocConsumer<AdBloc, AdState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is AdLoadSuccess) {
              _bannerAd = state.bannerAd;
              print('adloaded:::::::::::::: $_bannerAd');
            }

            if (state is AdLoadingError) {
              print('ERROR:::::::::::::::: ${state.message}');
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Home Screen'),
                  ),
                ),
                state is AdLoadSuccess
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd!),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And this is the bloc I created
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'ad_event.dart';
part 'ad_state.dart';

class AdBloc extends Bloc<AdEvent, AdState> {
  AdBloc() : super(AdInitial()) {
    on<AdInit>(initiateAdmob);
  }

  initiateAdmob(AdInit event, Emitter<AdState> emit) async {
    try {
      emit(AdLoading());
      final bannerAd = BannerAd(
        size: event.adSize,
        adUnitId: event.adUnitId,
        request: const AdRequest(),
        listener: BannerAdListener(
          // Called when an ad is successfully received.
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            // if (!mounted) {
            //   ad.dispose();
            //   return;
            // }
            // setState(() {
            // BannerAd? bAd;
            // bAd = ad as BannerAd;
            // if (ad == null) {
            //   ad.dispose();
            // }
            // else {
            //   print('BannerADD:::::::::::::::::::::: $bAd');
            //   emit(AdLoadSuccess(bannerAd: bAd!));
            // }

            // });
            emit(AdLoadSuccess(bannerAd: ad as BannerAd));
          },
          // Called when an ad request failed.
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
            debugPrint('BannerAd failed to load: $error');
            ad.dispose();
            emit(AdLoadingError(message: error.toString()));
          },
        ),
      );

      // Start loading.
      bannerAd.load();
      // print('ad::::::::: $bAd');

      // if (bAd != null) emit(AdLoadSuccess(bannerAd: bAd!));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AdLoadingError(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }
}

This is my state
part of 'ad_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class AdState {}

final class AdInitial extends AdState {}

class AdLoading extends AdState {}

class AdLoadingError extends AdState {
  final String message;

  AdLoadingError({required this.message});
}

class AdLoadSuccess extends AdState {
  final BannerAd bannerAd;

  AdLoadSuccess({required this.bannerAd});
}

This is my event
part of 'ad_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class AdEvent {}

class AdInit extends AdEvent {
  final AdSize adSize;
  final String adUnitId;

  AdInit({
    required this.adSize,
    required this.adUnitId,
  });
}

sorry if this is a messy code. I left the comments to your reference.
I don't know this is doable with bloc I just tried anyway.
Any info will help me to solve this issue.
Thankyou. :)

If you need a quick fix then try to add setState() in this section of your code:
if (state is AdLoadSuccess) {
   _bannerAd = state.bannerAd;
   setState(() {
     _bannerAd = ad as BannerAd;
   });
} 

But I must say that you're using Bloc the wrong way it's supposed to be used, I 'll give you something you should follow:

First try to move BannerAd? _bannerAd to your AdState class
in your initiateAdmob function, emit the BannerAd instace to your state
In your HomeScreen, try replace BlocConsumer to BlocBuilder, only listen to change of BannerAd in your AdState.

It is redundant when you already create a Bloc store your BannerAd value instead of your HomeScreen

I changed the code but I think the problem is inside the listener 'emit(AdLoadSuccess(bannerAd: ad as BannerAd)); emit is not coming to the ui. When I debug it it coming to the emit line and got to the state that's it.
